# How to select two verted id's in one gremlin-python query?

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

`
[image: example]

```
g.V().hasLabel('node1') \
    .as('prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3', 'prop4', 'prop5', 'prop6', 'prop7', 'node1_id_prop8', 'prop9') \
    .inE().hasLabel('edge').outV().hasLabel('node2').id().as('node2_id_prop10') \
    .select('prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3', 'prop4', 'prop5', 'prop6', 'prop7',
            'node1_id_prop8', 'prop9', 'node2_id_prop10') \
    .by('prop1').by('prop2').by('prop3').by('prop4').by('prop5') \
    .by(values('prop6').fold()).by('prop7').by(T.id).by('prop9').by(T.id).toList()
```

> Here I want to get values include both node ID's?
> But I am getting
> error message '{'requestId': '7abb9f32-a228-44fb-9206-8b034eb67aa5', 'status': {'message': '{"code":"InternalFailureException","requestId":"7abb9f32-a228-
> 44fb-9206-8b034eb67aa5","detailedMessage":"TokenTraversal support of java.lang.String does not allow selection by id"}', 'code': 500, 'attributes': {}}, 'result':
> {'data': None, 'meta': {}}}'
> `

I am expecting to get list of key value pair values that traverse through this node.

Answer (score 1):

With Gremlin, you typically want to follow a pattern where you're touching/fetching the higher level components in the graph first, and then applying filters and serialization techniques later in the query.

In your example, you want to traverse from node1 to node2 first and gather up those higher level components (the vertices) before starting to worry about the properties.  You can do that using `as()` or `aggregate()`...

> A side note here: You typically want to use labels as lower cardinality concepts. Think of them as groupings, or if coming from a relational database background, you can think of them as table names.  You typically would not have a vertex/node with a label of "node1".  It is more common that you would have a vertex/node with an ID of "node1".

```
g.V().hasLabel('node1').
    aggregate('v').
    inE().hasLabel('edge').outV().  # this can be simplified as in('edge')
    hasLabel('node2').
    aggregate('v').
```

The values in the aggregate then form a list that you can now select and perform other operations upon.  In this case, you want all of the available properties for each of those two vertices.  The `valueMap()` step creates a map of all properties associated with a vertex.  Adding `true` inside of the `valueMap()` adds the ID and label.  The `unfold()` step here is to unroll the aggregated list and pass each vertex in the list to `valueMap()`:

```
    select('v').
    unfold().
    valueMap(true)
```

That would get you a list of maps for each vertex in the following fashion:

```
[{
  <T.id: 1>: <id>,
  <T.label: 4>: 'node2',
  'Prop1': ['prop1']
 },{
  <T.id: 1>: <id>,
  <T.label: 4>: 'node1',
  'Prop1': ['prop1'],
  'Prop2': ['prop2'],
  'Prop3': ['prop3'],
  'Prop4': ['prop4'],
  'Prop5': ['prop5'],
   ...
  'Propn': ['propn']
}]
```